Possible to use shiny autoreload and port options in an interactive Quarto doc?
If developing an interactive Quarto document that embeds shiny, is it possible to turn on autoreload and have a fixed port, or is it better practice to develop the shiny app outside quarto before putting it in?
I see there are two shiny options
options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)
options(shiny.port = 5682)

..but it's not clear where to put those in the Quarto doc . They have no effect in the setup or server context..
